# "단어를 쓰려고 or 쓸려고 합니다"

Tags: grammar, orthography

I saw this sentence while surfing websites:

> 유의어를 짜내서라도 다른 단어를 **쓸려고** 합니다.

Is this sentence grammatically and orthographically correct?

Comment: The most correct and comprehensive answer to this is found under the question [Can you use -ㄹ려고 instead of -려고?](http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/392/can-you-use-%e3%84%b9%eb%a0%a4%ea%b3%a0-instead-of-%eb%a0%a4%ea%b3%a0)

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct.

In "다른 단어를 쓸려고 합니다", 쓸려고 is the combination of 쓸-([(1)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24444700) or [(2)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24444800))+ [-려고](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=11722200), but it is unnatural to use "쓸다" when the object is "단어". Instead, you can write "쓰려고", which is the combination of [쓰-](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24430700) + -려고.

> 유의어를 짜내서라도 다른 단어를 쓰려고 합니다.

**cf.** "쓸려고" can be used as:

> 마당을 빗자루로 쓸려고 한다.

See also: [here](http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=505) (Topic: Which is correct, "고치려고" or "고칠려고"?)

> **Answer:** "고치려고" is correct.